# Android app crashes from time to time after App was in background for a while, in ViewPager.getChildDrawingOrder

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, background, android-viewpager

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.getChildDrawingOrder(ViewPager.java:798)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.getAndVerifyPreorderedIndex(ViewGroup.java:1986)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.populateChildrenForAutofill(ViewGroup.java:3712)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildrenForAutofill(ViewGroup.java:3698)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(ViewGroup.java:3680)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(ViewGroup.java:3686)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(ViewGroup.java:3686)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(ViewGroup.java:3686)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(ViewGroup.java:3686)
   at android.app.assist.AssistStructure$WindowNode.<init>(AssistStructure.java:510)
   at android.app.assist.AssistStructure.<init>(AssistStructure.java:1912)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRequestAssistContextExtras(ActivityThread.java:3175)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Are you doing any operation on pager when Activity is in Paused State ? Provide [mcve]

Comment: I wish I could, I use ViewPager in more than 10 Classes and the Stacktrace doesn't include any line of my code, this makes it so hard to find.

Comment: And I don't use the pager in Paused State, as far as I know.

Comment: Just found out it happens when the hani-momanii:SuperNova-Emoji lib emoji popup is open and the app finishes in background and I reopen it.

Comment: So thats a library issue .. Check If this Emoji popup have lifecycle methods . File an issue on git ..

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I just overide the onDestroy Method of the activity like this:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    finish();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```